# join or concatenate values of a single column whose data type is NUMBER as a single string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

### Table structure

`|--------------------------------|
|column name  | column data type |
|------------ |------------------|
|branchid     |NUMBER(38)        |
|--------------------------------|`

### My SQL statement

`SELECT branchid FROM branchconfigs 
where branchconfigtypeid = (select branchconfigtypeid from branchconfigtypes where description = 'Show Branch Address');`

### Above query's output

branchid

`199
204
2850`

### My goal

To return all branchids as a single string separated by comma as shown below:

`'199,204,2850'`

### My attempt

`with rws as (
  select (SELECT to_char(branchid) FROM branchconfigs where branchconfigtypeid = (select branchconfigtypeid from branchconfigtypes where description = 'Show Branch Address')) as branchid 
  from ((SELECT to_char(branchid) FROM branchconfigs where branchconfigtypeid = (select branchconfigtypeid from branchconfigtypes where description = 'Show Branch Address')))
  connect by level <= (SELECT count(branchid) FROM branchconfigs where branchconfigtypeid = (select branchconfigtypeid from branchconfigtypes where description = 'Show Branch Address'))
)
  select listagg(branchid, ',') within group (order by branchid) 
  from   rws;`

### Error found after executing above query

`ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

### Expected output

`'199,204,2850'`

Any help, dear members ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite your query to use a join instead of a subquery.  Then, use `LISTAGG` to rollup the branch IDs into a single CSV string:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(bc.branchid, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY bc.branchid) branchids
FROM branchconfigs bc
INNER JOIN branchconfigtypes bct
    ON bc.branchconfigtypeid = bct.branchconfigtypeid
WHERE
    bct.description = 'Show Branch Address';
```